# Flutter Dynamic Boxes when click on plus button

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make 2 boxes in a row and my task when i click on first box then clock will open and it will take time as user choose. So clock is not a big issue but boxes are dynamic.

Just like there is a calendar above 2 boxes so when i click on monday then i will add multiple time in multiple boxes then after we click on tuesday then again new box will come then we will choose another time. So in every day of week we want dynamic box. Like if we click on plus icon then boxes will increase.

[image]

Comment: where do you want to add the boxes

Comment: when you click on plus button then 2 box will automatically add below  previous box

Comment: post the code you have tried so far. And what happens if i click multiple times on same day

Comment: bro, let us suppose this is like a coaching application.  we want to post a time on monday so we chhoose 8 AM to 12 PM. ok then after teacher wants to start another batch on same then he will  click on plus icon then he will enter 7PM to 8 pm. situation is like this. i think now you got it

Comment: did you tried any thing ?

Comment: i tried but that is static not dynamic

Comment: post the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

with out seeing your code I can't be 100% percent sure this is exactly what you want but you should be able to take if its not perfect you should be able to take it and make it fit your needs.

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(items[index]),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 300,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  onSubmitted: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      items.add(value);//this would go in your button
                    });
                    _controller.clear();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: If you need further help I can help you with this issue if not please accept this as the answer